# Tensorflow: Raw prediction output with large values

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a neural network in TensorFlow (1.8) which has (seemingly) large values for the output vector.  Here are some lines from a training session at about 1 hour into training, where we have a classification network for training to three labels (ie. classes).  The loss & accuracy for both training & test data can be seen, as well as the Standard Deviation of the three raw output values (`Ypred` node in listing below).  These are raw values before softmax.
These values seem unreasonably large compared to other NNs I've seen where the values should be much closer to one.

```
#1350000: Training Loss=89.791, Acc=0.735; Test Loss=79.961, Acc=0.792; RawStDev=[175.123, 382.312, 130.729, ]
#1360000: Training Loss=91.001, Acc=0.729; Test Loss=77.937, Acc=0.787; RawStDev=[172.724, 366.065, 134.253, ]
#1370000: Training Loss=86.340, Acc=0.751; Test Loss=83.953, Acc=0.773; RawStDev=[181.191, 383.081, 130.524, ]
#1380000: Training Loss=86.987, Acc=0.743; Test Loss=83.830, Acc=0.790; RawStDev=[182.473, 381.195, 137.126, ]
#1390000: Training Loss=88.804, Acc=0.729; Test Loss=79.096, Acc=0.787; RawStDev=[175.505, 371.759, 135.942, ]
#1400000: Training Loss=83.822, Acc=0.754; Test Loss=81.093, Acc=0.798; RawStDev=[173.978, 376.775, 136.153, ]
#1410000: Training Loss=85.469, Acc=0.735; Test Loss=79.343, Acc=0.793; RawStDev=[180.332, 386.373, 129.154, ]
#1420000: Training Loss=86.125, Acc=0.738; Test Loss=77.993, Acc=0.803; RawStDev=[190.086, 386.139, 129.828, ]
#1430000: Training Loss=85.288, Acc=0.732; Test Loss=82.180, Acc=0.782; RawStDev=[183.839, 381.932, 125.370, ]
#1440000: Training Loss=83.263, Acc=0.747; Test Loss=79.853, Acc=0.806; RawStDev=[177.329, 367.796, 125.690, ]
```

The code for the top three (dense) layers and the SGD definitions are shown below:

```
    with tf.name_scope('DensePost'):
        Xnew = tf.matmul(gathered, weights['Post1']) + biases['Post1']
        Xnew = tf.nn.dropout(Xnew, keep_prob)
        Xnew = tf.matmul(Xnew, weights['Post2']) + biases['Post2']
        Xnew = tf.nn.dropout(Xnew, keep_prob)
        Xnew = tf.matmul(Xnew, weights['Post3']) + biases['Post3']
        Xnew = tf.nn.dropout(Xnew, keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('DenseOut'):
        # Linear activation
        Ypred = tf.add(tf.matmul(Xnew, weights['out']), biases['out'], name="Ypred_raw")
        # Compute softmax result
        YpredSoftMax = tf.nn.softmax(Ypred, dim=1, name="Prediction")
        YpredIndex = tf.argmax(YpredSoftMax, axis=1, name="PredIndex")

        gd.node_name_output = "DenseOut/Ypred_raw"  # This is critical as this is needed for Freezing and for running Inferencing in Caelum

    # Loss, optimizer and evaluation; Regularization term
    l2 = gd.lambda_loss_amount * sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables())
    # L2 loss prevents this overkill neural network to overfit the data
    gd.cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=Ypred, labels=Ytrue)) + l2  # Softmax loss
    gd.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=gd.learning_rate).minimize(gd.cost)  # Adam Optimizer

    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(Ypred, 1), tf.argmax(Ytrue, 1))
    gd.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
```

My question: Is there something wrong with the training settings?  Or do we just need to run the training longer?

Comment: Might be that the learning rate is too high and/or your initialization is bad (too large values). You might need to provide more code.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give that try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed the initialization.  Once I switched over to `glorot` for the initializer on the fully connected layers, the values started smaller and settled faster:

```
initializer=tf.glorot_uniform_initializer
```